# How to correlate start/end events from an infinite stream?

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming

I have a stream of events from rabbitMQ that look like
`Event: {id, type, timestamp}`.
The values are:
`id`: some unique string
`type`: (a)rrive/(d)epart

I want to generate a new stream of events where I match an arrive event to a depart event (consecutive) for each id. Events with the same id can appear
so for example given a stream of Events:

```
id | type | time  
1  |  a   | 0  
1  |  d   | 1   
2  |  a   | 2  
3  |  a   | 3  
3  |  d   | 4  
1  |  a   | 5  
2  |  d   | 6
1  |  d   | 7
```

I would generate a new stream of type `Correlated:{id, duration}`:
where `duration` is the difference in timestamp from the two correlated events

```
id | duration  
{1, 1}  
{3, 1}  
{2, 4}
{1, 1}
```

I've been able to group the incoming stream by id, but haven't been able to find any documentation on correlating on event to another. I'm using RxJS

Comment: So `length` is really `duration`? i.e. the difference between the time of arrival and the time of departure?

Comment: yes, I've edited the question to clarify this point.

Comment: If there are multiple arrivals and departures for a given id, you should really make that clear by including that in your example data.

Comment: sorry about that, I've updated.

Comment: I considered grouping the stream by id, then type and using [buffer](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-buffer) with the `departure` stream for each id acting as the closingNotifier. Not sure if this could be the right direction?

Comment: Yeah, that is the right direction - see the answer - but when using notifiers derived from the source stream itself, you often (always?) need to be careful, as the order of subscriptions becomes important. In this case, it can be done without resorting to a notification stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the arrivals precede the departures, after the `groupBy`, you can use `pairwise` to combine consecutive events, `filter` to consider only departures and `map` to calculate the duration, like this:

```js
const source = Rx.Observable.of(
  { id: 1, type: "a", time: 0 },
  { id: 1, type: "d", time: 1 },
  { id: 2, type: "a", time: 2 },
  { id: 3, type: "a", time: 3 },
  { id: 3, type: "d", time: 4 },
  { id: 1, type: "a", time: 5 },
  { id: 2, type: "d", time: 6 },
  { id: 1, type: "d", time: 7 },
  Rx.Scheduler.async
);

const grouped = source
  .groupBy(event => event.id)
  .mergeMap(group => group
    .pairwise()
    .filter(([, last]) => last.type === "d")
    .map(([prev, last]) => ({
      id: last.id,
      duration: last.time - prev.time
    }))
  );

grouped.subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: arrivals will precede departures, however there will not be only one arrival/departure for each id. That said, I want to correlate each arrival with the next departure for that id. I'll give this a go and see where it takes me